# Select all entries with no duplicates?

Tags: sql

I have the table `productos`:

```
nombre  Precio  Tienda   Departamento

  A      23      Belén     Hogar
  B      12      Belén     Hogar
  C      56      Belén     Hogar
  C      32      Terra     Hogar
  D      10      Belén     Hogar
  E      8       Belén     Hogar
  E      9       Terra     Hogar
```

And I need to select all entries on table `productos`, however on products with multiple entries I want the one with the highest price, regardless it being on the same `tienda` or not.

Comment: Hope the translation fits all your description and welcome to SO.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.*
  from productos p
  join (select nombre, max(precio) as max_precio
          from productos
         group by nombre) v
    on p.nombre = v.nombre
   and p.precio = v.max_precio
```

The following would eliminate ties in Oracle or SQL Server or PostgreSQL (please specify the database you're using if you're not using Oracle or SQL Server):

```
select *
  from (select nombre,
               precio,
               tienda,
               departamento,
               row_number() over(partition by nombre order by nombre, precio desc, tienda, departamento) as rn
          from productos) x
 where rn = 1
```

**Fiddle example with a tie being eliminated:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b40d/4/0

Comment: Brian if the table have 1 product double with the same highest price, how I do to select only one. whichever

Comment: Are the tienda/department fields different on those rows at least? Also what database are you using (Oracle, sql server, mysql, postgresql, etc.)?

Comment: @rbklc I added a way to eliminate ties in Oracle, SQL Server, or PostgreSQL. If you're not using any of those databases, please specify the database that you are using. The solution depends on the database.

Comment: I use postgresql, and could be different or equal.

Comment: @rbklc should work in postgresql, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6b40d/1/0 , notice how A is listed only once